# Convert / transform XML to XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert XML to XSL ( Style Sheet ) but getting error with it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<id>004</id>
<number>006</number>
<ErrorMessage/><status>pass</status>
<time>2020-08-07T10:32:31Z</time>
</root>
```

I have created this StyleSheet but getting the error to while reading.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:value-of select="/root/status"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Error :

[image]

I would appreciate your help.
thank you.

Comment: _"getting error"_ what is the error??

Comment: @DanielHaley updated the questions , sorry. with error.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your (corrected) code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4x  It seems you are not initiating the transformation correctly. -- P.S. There is no such thing as *"convert / transform XML to XSL"*. Your stylesheet processes an XML and extracts a single value into a text output.

Comment: I've tested successfully your XSL against your XML using xalan-2.7.0 CLI. What tool are you invoking (and how) to do the transformation? I suspect there is something wrong with the way you invoke it.

Comment: @LittleSanti - its Vantage Server - very specific Media engine. can you pls give me hint how did you test with Xalan ?

Comment: Read https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html to transform with Xalan CLI. You can also add a `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my.xsl"?>` after the XML declaration and open it with Internet Explorer, and it will perform the transformation (or report an error if there is any).